# anchor tag vertical scroll only, disable horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, anchor

I have a page with a menu on the lefthand side, which contains anchors to elements in the right hand side.
When clicking the left hand anchors, I would like it to scroll vertically only (not horizontally), so that the left hand menu stays on the screen no matter what.
Basically, I want a vertical-only anchor.

Comment: Show us some code that you have tried.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is only an issue when the user has a small screen (or makes their browser window small) and the horizontal scrollbar kicks in. When the page fits the screen with no horizontal scrollbar, its fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use just jquery like so:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
 target = this.id.offset().top;
 $('html,body').animate({
   scrollTop: target
  }, 1000);
event.preventDefault();
}
```

"On click on any link inside the page, get the offset from the top of the page and anmiate the scroll down to that position over the span of 1second."

Or use this plugin http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html for more control.

Comment: Thanks. The scrollTop was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

A drop-in solution, vanilla JS:

```
const scrolledParentSelector = ".app-content"; // or e.g. body
const scrolled = document.querySelector(scrolledParentSelector);

const anchors = document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='#']"); // hash tag anchor href starts with '#'
anchors.forEach(a => {
  a.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const href = a.getAttribute("href").slice(1); // remove initial '#'
    const target = document.querySelector(`[id='${href}']`);
    const top = target.offsetTop;
    scrolled.scrollTop = top;
  };
});
```